# Rails undefined method email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a function to send an email to a principal once a form is submitted.

This is in my

```
pdforms_controller.rb
```

---

```
@principal = User.where(role: 'principal', office: current_user.office).first
```

If I go into index.html.erb and use the following line

```
<%= principal.email %>
```

It prints the email ttyler@duneland.k12.in.us to the screen.

I have an action mailer in my create function to alert the principal once a pdform is created..

```
NewPdform.notify_principal(@principal).deliver
```

This is my `new_pdform.rb` file

```
def notify_principal(principal)
    @principal = principal
    mail(to: @principal.email, subject: 'principal email')
end
```

For whatever reason, when I `pdform#create` the form, I am getting the following error.

> undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

If I can call @principal.email in my index view, why can I not use that same call in the mailer function to send it to that email? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Try changing NewPdform.notify_principal(@principal.email).deliver to 
NewPdform.notify_principal(@principal).deliver

Comment: Stupid question:  are you querying the principal data from the DB in your create method?

Comment: @eezee No i am not.

Comment: Try doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments, we determined that you weren't querying the DB's User table in your create method.

This isn't the best explanation however:  each request to the server corresponds to a controller & action (method in the controller).  These are independent requests.  Instance variables in the controller are shared with the views that correspond to the action.  They are shared between controller methods but not on separate requests.

Hope that helps.  If someone has more insight, please refine this.